# Edit the base_css Stylesheet

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

Is it possibe to edit the base_css stylesheet to define your own stylesheet to create custom timecards? If not, can we create a separate stylesheet and apply it to the timecards?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit the included base stylesheet, but you can define your own styles using a `<style>` element within an html card.

Answer (score 0):

you can also override same CSS class in separate stylesheet.